# Get data from webservice and put on map

Tags: android, json, web-services, rest, maps

I am doing an application on Android that gets locations from a webservice and puts it on a map. The app should do it every 15 seconds. What is the best way to do this?The communicaton with the webservice is made using REST architecture and the webservice returns a JSON. Should i use a Service or AsyncTask? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You'll for sure see different opinions around here regarding this topic, but I've been using [ExecutorServices](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) for a while and they work really nice. Don't forget to stop it whenever the activity pauses.

Remainder: if the application should be an always running thing (for example a GPS navigation, or some type of location based social gaming) then you might want to use a Service that will also use an ExecutorService and don't forget to put a Notification letting users know that it's still running and that they can cancel if they wish to.

Comment: just to add it up, you'll probably want to use either `scheduleAtFixedRate` or `scheduleWithFixedDelay`